# c++ recursive quicksort infinite loop

Tags: c++, quicksort

So I've been having a problem with a c++ program that quicksorts an array of integers. When I have more than six elements in my array, the sort infinitely loops for some reason. I think I've isolated the problem to the choosing of mm pivotal value, but I can't work out for the life of me why it's causing it to break.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int getPivot(int begin,int end){//Takes length of array as input and returns the position of the pivot
    int len = end-begin;
    if(len < 3){
        return end;
    }else{
        return 2;
    }
};

void quickSort(int begin, int end, int arr[]){
    int pivot = arr[getPivot(begin,end)];//get Pivotal value - If I replace this with just 0 then there are no problems...
    int tempLeft = begin, tempRight = end;
    int temp;
    while(tempLeft <= tempRight){
        while(arr[tempLeft] < pivot){//Find a point where there are 2 elements that need to be swapped
            tempLeft++;
        }
        while(arr[tempRight] > pivot){
            tempRight--;
        }
        if(tempLeft <= tempRight){
            temp = arr[tempLeft];//Swap the elements
            arr[tempLeft] = arr[tempRight];
            arr[tempRight] = temp;
            tempLeft++;//Skip these swapped elements in the sort
            tempRight--;
        }
    }
    if (begin < tempRight){//Only recurse lower if the new sub array has a length greater than 1
        quickSort(begin, tempRight, arr);
    }
    if (tempLeft < end){
        quickSort(tempLeft, end, arr);
    }
}

main() {
    int array[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int length = 7;
    quickSort(0,length-1,array);
}
```

You will probably ask why I have such a weird way of choosing my pivotal value, but lets just say that for this instance the pivotal value has to be the third element in each sublist or if the sub list is smaller than 3 it is the last item in the sublist.

The reason I think the problem is associated with the pivotal value is because when I replace my method of choosing a pivot with just using the first element in the sublist I don't have any problems.

If run, as is now the program, will segfault after looping infinitely but if the array being sorted is one element shorter, it will work fine. That has had me baffled for hours now, and I can't work out what the problem is. If anyone has any tips or suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use `std::sort`? (e.g., recreational reasons?)

Comment: print or debug and see where it's caught

Comment: Yeah I'm not using std::sort so I can get a feel for how the algorithm works. 
I've also done a lot of printing test cases to try and find where it's getting caught up but so far all I could tell was that it was getting caught in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quickSort(3,6,arr)` will always call `quickSort(3,6,arr)`.

I think you miss

```
int getPivot(int begin,int end)
{
    //Takes length of array as input and returns the position of the pivot
    int len = end-begin;
    if(len < 3){
        return end;
    }else{
        return 2+begin; // Here
    }
};
```

EDIT: Clarification

`GetPivot(3,6)` will return 2, instead should return an index between 3 and 6.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you saying that the program will constantly call quickSort(3,6,arr) and that's whats causing the infinite loop? If this is the case what could I do to prevent this?

Comment: Yes that's what cause your infinite loop. Not selecting properly the pivot index. `getPivot()` actually should be named as `GetPivotIndex()`

Comment: My god... Of course it needed to add the beginning value... That seems to have solved everything. Thank you very much! (excuse me while I bang my head on the wall for missing something so simple).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the median of three approach for your pivot.  It is a little more robust.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void myswap(int* arr, int left, int right)
{
    int swap = arr[left];
    arr[left] = arr[right];
    arr[right] = swap;
}

int getPivotIndex(int* arr, int begin, int end){
    int middle = (begin + end) / 2;

    if (arr[end] < arr[begin])
    {
        myswap(arr, begin, end);
    }

    if (arr[middle] < arr[begin])
    {
        myswap(arr, middle, begin);
    }

    if (arr[end] < arr[middle])
    {
        myswap(arr, end, middle);
    }

    return middle;
};


void quickSort(int begin, int end, int* arr){
    int pivot = arr[getPivotIndex(arr, begin, end)];
    int tempLeft = begin, tempRight = end;
    while (tempLeft <= tempRight){
        while (arr[tempLeft] < pivot){
            tempLeft++;
        }
        while (arr[tempRight] > pivot){
            tempRight--;
        }
        if (tempLeft <= tempRight){
            myswap(arr, tempLeft, tempRight);
            tempLeft++;
            tempRight--;
        }
     }
    if (begin < tempRight){
        quickSort(begin, tempRight, arr);
    }
    if (tempLeft < end){
        quickSort(tempLeft, end, arr);
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 6, 0, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1 }; // Test we are actually sorting
    int length = 7;
    quickSort(0, length - 1, array);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "array[" << i << "]: " << array[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```